# Checkbox Change / Click event not firing

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox

I have a problem with a checkbox click event.
A user is to fill out 5 inputs which create global variables of the input value.
The user then fills out the rest of the form and then clicks a verification checkbox to agree to the rules/regulations. This checkbox should populate a hidden textarea with the 5 variables mixed in with some pre-determined text.

It seems to be working for the most part however I am receiving some blank entries. Therefore the checkbox trigger event isn't firing properly. I have done extensive browser testing and cannot pinpoint the cause.

I am working with some custom code on the Shortstack App Platform which is for contests/sweepstakes for facebook.

I have tried both the following to trigger the event but neither fixes the problem.

```
$('#promotion_agree').change(function() {
```

and

```
$('#promotion_agree').on("click", function(event) {
```

My code is below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

//Fade out the Agree to Rules/Regulations checkbox

$('#promotion_agree_block').fadeOut();

//Input Field 1
$('#promotion_custom_field_2').bind("keyup change", function() {
  fieldone = $(this).val();
  $('#promotion_custom_field_5').val(fieldone);
});

//Input Field 2
$('#promotion_custom_field_3').bind("keyup change", function() {
  fieldtwo = $(this).val();
  $('#promotion_custom_field_7').val(fieldtwo);
});

//Input Field 3
$('#promotion_custom_field_4').bind("keyup change", function() {
  fieldthree = $(this).val();
  $('#promotion_custom_field_8').val(fieldthree);
});

//Input Field 4
 $('#promotion_custom_field_17').bind("keyup change", function() {
   fieldfour = $(this).val();
   $('#promotion_custom_field_9').val(fieldfour);
});

//Input Field 5
$('#promotion_custom_field_18').bind("keyup change", function() {
  fieldfive = $(this).val();
  $('#promotion_custom_field_37').val(fieldfive);
  $('#promotion_agree_block').fadeIn();  
});



////Post the global variables to the hidden textarea along with the included text

$('#promotion_agree').on("click", function(event) { 

//The following code is placed in the textarea field that is hidden

$('#promotion_image_description').html('' + fieldone + ' walked through The Fair, after     enjoying the Superdogs show where he saw lots of ' + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ' dogs. They leapt through hoops and over jumps and ' + fieldfour + ' with their trainers. He thought about how great it would be if his dog ' + fieldfive + ' became a Superdog! Maybe one day...\r\n\r\n Submitted Words: ' + fieldone + ', ' + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ', ' + fieldfour + ', ' + fieldfive + ''.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n')); 


  });
});
</script>
```

**Edit to Original Post Below...**

HTML Code Looks Like This:

This is what one of the inputs looks like:

```
<div class="field_block custom_field_2_field_block text_field_type_block center-input" id="promotion_custom_field_2_block">
<label for="promotion_custom_field_2"><span class="main_field_label">Field One</span><span class="required">*</span></label>
<input class="small" id="promotion_custom_field_2" name="promotion[custom_field_2]" type="text">
</div>
```

This is the checkbox that triggers the event to post to the textarea:

```
<div class="field_block agree_field_block black-text" id="promotion_agree_block" style="display: block;">
<label for="promotion_agree"><input id="promotion_agree" name="promotion[agree]" type="checkbox" value="1"> <span class="main_field_label">I have read and agree to the rules &amp; regulations</span><span class="required">*</span></label>
</div>
```

Text Area Looks Like this after the Checkbox above is checked.

```
<div class="field_block image_description_field_block" id="promotion_image_description_block">
<label for="promotion_image_description"><span class="main_field_label">MadLib Story</span></label>
<textarea class="medium" id="promotion_image_description" name="promotion[image_description]">test1 walked through The Fair, after enjoying the Superdogs show where he saw lots of test2, test3 dogs. They leapt through hoops and over jumps and test4 with their trainers. He thought about how great it would be if his dog test5 became a Superdog! Maybe one day...
```

Submitted Words: test1, test2, test3, test4, test5

**Second Edit**
Here's an Edit to my Javascript Code to populate the Description Field as each element is typed in. The form will not populate the description text on submit for some reason so I thought this might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


$('#promotion_custom_field_2').bind("keyup change", function() {
//Create Global Variable for Text entered
  fieldone = $(this).val();

  //Add Global Variable to Hidden Field
  $('#promotion_custom_field_5').val(fieldone);

  //Update Description Field if Changed
  $('#promotion_image_description').html('' + fieldone + ' walked through The Fair, after enjoying the Superdogs show where he saw lots of '
                                         + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ' dogs. They leapt through hoops and over jumps and ' 
                                         + fieldfour + ' with their trainers. He thought about how great it would be if his dog ' 
                                         + fieldfive + ' became a Superdog! Maybe one day...\r\n\r\n Submitted Words: ' + fieldone + ', ' + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ', ' + fieldfour + ', ' + fieldfive + ''.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n'));

});



$('#promotion_custom_field_3').bind("keyup change", function() {
//Create Global Variable for Text entered
  fieldtwo = $(this).val();

  //Add Global Variable to Hidden Field
  $('#promotion_custom_field_7').val(fieldtwo);

  //Update Description Field if Changed
  $('#promotion_image_description').html('' + fieldone + ' walked through The Fair, after enjoying the Superdogs show where he saw lots of '
                                         + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ' dogs. They leapt through hoops and over jumps and ' 
                                         + fieldfour + ' with their trainers. He thought about how great it would be if his dog ' 
                                         + fieldfive + ' became a Superdog! Maybe one day...\r\n\r\n Submitted Words: ' + fieldone + ', ' + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ', ' + fieldfour + ', ' + fieldfive + ''.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n'));


});

$('#promotion_custom_field_4').bind("keyup change", function() {
//Create Global Variable for Text entered
  fieldthree = $(this).val();

  //Add Global Variable to Hidden Field
  $('#promotion_custom_field_8').val(fieldthree);

  //Update Description Field if Changed
  $('#promotion_image_description').html('' + fieldone + ' walked through The Fair, after enjoying the Superdogs show where he saw lots of '
                                         + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ' dogs. They leapt through hoops and over jumps and ' 
                                         + fieldfour + ' with their trainers. He thought about how great it would be if his dog ' 
                                         + fieldfive + ' became a Superdog! Maybe one day...\r\n\r\n Submitted Words: ' + fieldone + ', ' + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ', ' + fieldfour + ', ' + fieldfive + ''.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n'));

});

   $('#promotion_custom_field_17').bind("keyup change", function() {
   //Create Global Variable for Text entered
  fieldfour = $(this).val();

  //Add Global Variable to Hidden Field
  $('#promotion_custom_field_9').val(fieldfour);

  //Update Description Field if Changed
  $('#promotion_image_description').html('' + fieldone + ' walked through The Fair, after enjoying the Superdogs show where he saw lots of '
                                         + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ' dogs. They leapt through hoops and over jumps and ' 
                                         + fieldfour + ' with their trainers. He thought about how great it would be if his dog ' 
                                         + fieldfive + ' became a Superdog! Maybe one day...\r\n\r\n Submitted Words: ' + fieldone + ', ' + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ', ' + fieldfour + ', ' + fieldfive + ''.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n')); 

});

   $('#promotion_custom_field_18').bind("keyup change", function() {
//Create Global Variable for Text entered
  fieldfive = $(this).val();

  //Add Global Variable to Hidden Field
  $('#promotion_custom_field_37').val(fieldfive);

  //Update Description Field if Changed
  $('#promotion_image_description').html('' + fieldone + ' walked through The Fair, after enjoying the Superdogs show where he saw lots of '
                                         + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ' dogs. They leapt through hoops and over jumps and ' 
                                         + fieldfour + ' with their trainers. He thought about how great it would be if his dog ' 
                                         + fieldfive + ' became a Superdog! Maybe one day...\r\n\r\n Submitted Words: ' + fieldone + ', ' + fieldtwo + ', ' + fieldthree + ', ' + fieldfour + ', ' + fieldfive + ''.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n')); 


 });


  });
  </script>
```

Comment: is the code inside dom ready.... also share the html markup

Comment: I see you are using both `bind` and `on`, what version of jQuery are you using? ... also, are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No console errors. Checked it with IE developer tools as well. Because I am using shortstack, the form is auto generated so I can't control the html except adding a class. Very difficult to pull the html but i'll see what I can piece together.

Comment: Just copy the  HTML from the element inspector

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just store some values in a hidden element which you don't seem to be using elsewhere, so how do you know the function hasn't been triggered?

Comment: I have added some sample HTML code for the elements in question. Note that the input .bind events are also posting the global variable to hidden input fields which seems to be working fine on all browsers: $('#promotion_custom_field_5').val(fieldone);

Answer (score 1):

Try this for checkbox change event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            alert("Checked");
             //$(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");
           }else{
            alert("Unchecked")  
           }
        });

});
```

Comment: Grabbing the checkbox by id as the OP is attempting would make more sense (in case there are other checkboxes), the OP said he has already tried using `change()` and the callback isn't getting ran so at this point there is no reason to worry about whether it is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and saw this post.

Since I am just doing a test I decided to just put the click call on the checkbox:

```
<input id="chk_selected" name="chk_selected" type="checkbox"
       value="@x.GetValue("pic_pk_Idx_n")" onclick="clickchange(this)" />
```

So I would say if you have this problem, use this.

However, it is important to work out why the following lines are having problems:

```
$('#chk_selected').change(function () {
    $('#chk_selected').on("click", function (event) {
```

Note that this could be a jQuery version problem (I had this problem in my AJAX calls).